# Replicate Server 2003 DFS root to Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, replication, dfs, file-replication-services

I am trying to get a Windows Server 2003 (not R2) DFS root to replicate to Server 2008 Standard.

My research so far suggests that adding the File Replication Service role service in the File Services role on Server 2008 should allow DFS replication with Server 2000/2003:

> File Replication Service (FRS) supports synchronizing folders with file servers that use FRS instead of the newer DFS Replication service. To enable a server to synchronize folders with servers that use FRS with the Windows Server 2003 or Windows 2000 implementations of Distributed File System, install File Replication Service.

That's from Server Manager in Server 2008.

However when I right click our root target in DFS on Server 2003 and run through the New Root Target wizard, I get all the way to the end, but when I click Finish I get the following error:

> The following error occurred while creating DFS root on server srv-file:
>   The Distributed File System service cannot be contacted on the specified server. Possible causes include the service is not started, the server is offline, network problems are preventing access to the server, or a firewall is blocking port 445 on the server.

The NTFRS service is running on the 2008 server and there are no firewalls enabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you need to install the new-style DFS stuff on Server 2008 as well to make this work. Problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on the File Replication Service after you install the Role and set it to automatic.